# PHP Script stop running on Shared Host

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, timeout, simple-html-dom

I really tried to find an answer in each question here and on google and I couldn't find any.

My php code just stop running in the middle of the code and at different times every time I run the code. I don't think it's a problem with CURL function, because the code stops sometimes before or after the CURL function call. I don't think It's a code error because the code runs correctly while it's running. I guess it's a 'timeout' problem with the shared hosting.

My code basically do a "web scrape" with simple_html_dom library and curl functions. I'm running it on a shared web hosting (hostgator) and I tried to run it through CRON JOB also, and it didn't work too.

I've already set the variables at the beginning of the code (and also changed the variables on PHP.INI) and didn't work:

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('memory_limit',-1);
```

The full code (I've shortened a bit, in the original code I put some different dates and call 'scrape' function many times):

```
    require('simple_html_dom.php');
    
    
    //get today's date
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    
    if (date('H') < '9') {
        
        $date_period = "today";
        $date_period_date = date('Y-m-d');
        
        $puDay = date('j');
        $puMonth = date('n');
        $puYear = date('Y');
        $doDay = date('j', strtotime(' + 1 days')); 
        $doMonth = date('n', strtotime(' + 1 days')); 
        $doYear = date('Y', strtotime(' + 1 days'));
    
        scrape($puDay,$puMonth,$puYear,$doDay,$doMonth,$doYear,$date_period, $today, $date_period_date, $location_id,$location,$city);
    
        
        unset($date_period,$date_period_date,$puDay,$puMonth,$puYear,$doDay,$doMonth,$doYear);
        
        
        }
        
    
    //functions

    function scrape($puDay_aux, $puMonth_aux, $puYear_aux, $doDay_aux, $doMonth_aux, $doYear_aux, $period_id_aux, $curDate_aux, $periodDate_aux, $location_id_aux,$location_aux,$city_aux){
        
      $bad_proxy = "";
        
        $check = 1;
        
        do{
        
            $link = "my link";
    
        
            $best_proxy = get_best_proxy($link, $bad_proxy);
        
            $scraped_page = curl($link, $best_proxy);
            $html = new simple_html_dom();
            $html->load($scraped_page);
            $check_end = strpos($html,'</html>');
            
            if(!empty($html)) {

                if ($check_end===FALSE) {
                    
                  $check = $check + 1;
                  $bad_proxy = $best_proxy;
    
                } else {
                
                    
                    foreach($html->find('table[class=ResultRow]') as $element) 
                    {
                        $supplier = $element->find('h4',0);

                            unset($supplier,$supplier_aux,$car,$car_aux,$price,$price_aux,$priceBRL);
    
                    }

                    $html->clear();
                    unset($link,$html,$best_proxy,$stream,$context);
                    
                    
                    $check = 5;
    
            
                    } 
                
                
            } else {
                
                    $check = $check + 1;    
                 
            }
    
        
        } while ($check<5);
        
    }
    
    

function get_best_proxy($link, $bad_proxy){
      
    
        $proxy_array = array(
    '177.184.144.130:8080',
    '177.6.147.202:8080',
    '187.44.1.167:8080',
    '170.82.228.42:8080',
    '177.72.1.102:8080',
    '138.185.101.20:8080',
    '187.102.149.178:8080',
    '177.32.12.127:8080',
    '189.38.3.9:8080',
    '138.185.101.21:8080'                      
    );
    
        $i=0;
    
        foreach ($proxy_array as $key){
          
          if ($key != $bad_proxy) {
    
              $proxy_speed = proxy_speed($key, $link);
              $proxy_speed_result[$i] = $proxy_speed;

              if ($proxy_speed<9999999){break;}
            
              $i++;
            
          }
          
        }
        
        $min = array_keys($proxy_speed_result, min($proxy_speed_result));

        $min_aux = $min[0];
     
            
        $proxy_output = $proxy_array[$min_aux];
        
        return($proxy_output);
        
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    function proxy_speed($proxy, $link) {
    
          $link = "my link here";
                $loadingtime = time();
                $theHeader = curl_init($link);
                curl_setopt($theHeader, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
          curl_setopt($theHeader, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
          curl_setopt($theHeader, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
          curl_setopt($theHeader, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
          curl_setopt($theHeader, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1a2pre) Gecko/2008073000 Shredder/3.0a2pre ThunderBrowse/3.2.1.8");
          curl_setopt($theHeader, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
          curl_setopt($theHeader, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
          curl_setopt($theHeader, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
          curl_setopt($theHeader, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);      
          curl_setopt($theHeader, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
          curl_setopt($theHeader, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy); 
          $curlResponse = curl_exec($theHeader);
                
                if ($curlResponse === false) 
                {
                    return 9999999;
                } 
                else 
                {

                    return (time() - $loadingtime);
                }
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    function curl($url, $proxy) {
           
    
        
                    
            $options = Array(
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,  // Setting cURL's option to return the webpage data
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,  // Setting cURL to follow 'location' HTTP headers
                CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => TRUE, // Automatically set the referer where following 'location' HTTP headers
                CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 300,   // Setting the amount of time (in seconds) before the request times out
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 300,  // Setting the maximum amount of time for cURL to execute queries
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, // Setting the maximum number of redirections to follow
                CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1a2pre) Gecko/2008073000 Shredder/3.0a2pre ThunderBrowse/3.2.1.8",  // Setting the useragent
                CURLOPT_URL => $url, // Setting cURL's URL option with the $url variable passed into the function
                CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL => 1,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
                CURLOPT_PROXY => $proxy
                    );
             
            $ch = curl_init();  // Initialising cURL 
            $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch , CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);   // Setting cURL's options using the previously assigned array data in $options
            $data = curl_exec($ch); // Executing the cURL request and assigning the returned data to the $data variable
           
            if ($data === false) $data = curl_error($ch);
                return stripslashes($data);
            curl_close($ch);
        }
```

Does anyone know what's happening here? Does my web hosting timing out?
Thanks!

Comment: https://support.hostgator.com/articles/php-settings-that-cannot-be-changed says `max_execution_time=30` cannot be changed or exceeded.

Comment: Thanks. They've told me that too, but my code runs for more than 30 seconds. The code usually runs for almost 5 minutes.